# Is there a better way to write this script in python

Tags: python, email, scripting, alerts

I know this is sloopy, I'm a beginner but is there  a better way to do this, I feel like there is but I don't know. What I'm trying to do is, send an  email alert any time a score change that higher then 9.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Script to send any pending alerts via email
"""

import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

#### begin


def send_email(): 
print "Begin GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s " % (datetime.now()).

if 'score_by_cat' >=9: 
        send_email()

 if 'score_by_cat' >=9:
       print( "Send Email")
    else:
       print('Nothing")




print "Begin GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s " % (datetime.now())


client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:28057/')
db = client.factor

email_rcpt_list = ['example@momo.com']
                  ['example2@momo.com']  

#process the alert..  if it is high enough risk and the makes sense (not a security control etc)

    for alert in db.risk_alerts.find({"$and" : [{'sent': False}]}):
        if float(alert['metric'])>=9 and alert['category']!='security control':
            #Call email send here
            for email in email_rcpt_list:
                print 'Call email and pass in the email address from email_rcpt_list'
                print ' Sample alert:  Vendor: %s  Has an new item %s on %s  of elevated risk %s in the category %s link: https://Gamer-dev.momo.net/profile/view/detail/%s' % (alert['vendor_name'],alert['key'],alert['source'],alert['metric'],alert['category'],alert['profile_id']) 
    #mark as sent always
    db.risk_alerts.update_one({"_id":alert['_id']},{"$set": {"sent":True}})

print "End GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s" % (datetime.now())
```

Comment: Are you sure this script even works at the first place? `if 'score_by_cat' >=9` without colon `:`?

Comment: Yeah there seem to be formatting issues going on here. And in python, formatting is important, so we need to see it correctly formatted.

Comment: Okay, Sorry about that I will edit it

Comment: My personal style is always to factorise out a large number of repetitions such as those `alert`s using `.format( *( alert(x) for x in ("vendor_name","source","key",...) ))`. Format-specific you can also do `"...{0[vendor_name]} ... {0[source]} ... ".format(alert)`. That's probably tangential to the question, though.

Comment: @jon Also, if you already have workable code you're looking to improve you might want to consider [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first few lines of your code:

```
if 'score_by_cat' >=9

print "Begin GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s " % (datetime.now())
timestamp=datetime.utcnow()
```

Conditional statements (e.g., `if`, `else`, `for`) must end with a colon (`:`). I believe that the second line should be indented (if the score is >=9, then emails must be sent). Also, `timestamp=datetime.utcnow()` was NOT used in this code; hence, you can remove this line.

Now go and recheck your code for potential formatting errors.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: Thanks, I will do that now, like I said I'm a beginner

Comment: Just a question but is there a way I can turn all of that into a function and simply call it in the if statement?

Comment: By "all of that", you mean this:

Comment: `print "Begin GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s " % (datetime.now())
timestamp=datetime.utcnow()`?

Comment: You can use: `def send_email(): print "Begin GAMER-ALERT-SEND-EMAILS %s " % (datetime.now())`. Then, you can reformat the previous lines to: `if 'score_by_cat' >=9: send_email()`

Comment: SO I will begin with defining the Send mail function